# How to maximize ckeditor from external javascript event?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

Normally maxmize/minimize ckeditor using tool bar button. But i want maximize/minimize the ckeditor screen using external js.For example just i click any other button in the page ckeditor automatically go to maximize.

Comment: CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.execCommand('maximize')

Comment: thanks. it's working...!